# Cannot implicitly convert type string to int in C#

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to c# and I can't figure this out. The error says that I cannot convert string to int implicitly. Here is a snippet of my code. Thanks!

```
    private static int GenerateLetters(int size, bool lowercase) //added a return type
    {
        {
        string randomLetters = string.Empty;
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            randomLetters += Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 90));                
        }

        if (lowercase)
            return randomLetters.ToLower();
        else
            return randomLetters.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: here you are converting `randomLetters` into string using tostring and returning it... and in heading you have taken `int` value... that's why you are getting this error... Please change either of them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change return type of your method to `string`

```
private static string GenerateLetters(...)
```

By the way it would be better if you change your method like this:

```
private static string GenerateLetters(int size, bool lowercase) //added a return type
{

     char[] chars = new char[size];
     Random r = new Random();

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         chars[i] = Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 90));
     }

    if (lowercase)
           return new String(chars).ToLower();
     else
          return new String(chars);

}
```

Comment: `chars[i] = Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 90));` not `+=`

Comment: @user3248531 your welcome and please consider accepting my answer if it's solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
private static int GenerateLetters
```

to

```
private static string GenerateLetters
```

you are returning string but method has return parameter int. What you are returning has to be compatible with method stub.

Read more about [methods in c# at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)